# Getting BadRequest Error while Writing JUnit Test for MvcMock Post method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking

I am writing a JUnit test using MvcMock to simulate HTTP post request. However my test is continuously failing with BadRequest error. How can I make the test case PASS

Rest end point - **/transaction**

Request format is JSON -

```
{   
        "amount" : 12.6,
        "timestamp": 1478192204001
    }
```

**Transaction.java** class which I have written is -

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Transaction {
    private double amount;

    private Instant timestamp;

    public Transaction() {
    }

    public Transaction(double amount, Instant timestamp) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Instant getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Instant timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

JUnit test which I have written is below -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers=TransactionController.class)
public class TransactionControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private TransactionService service;

    @Test
    public void shouldPostTransaction() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception {
        final Transaction transaction = new Transaction(14.1, now());

        when(service.add(transaction)).thenReturn(true);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mvc.perform(
                post("/transactions")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(transaction))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().string(""))
                .andReturn();

        verify(service).add(transaction);
    }
}
```

**TransactionController.java** which I have written is -

```
@RestController
public class TransactionController {
    @Autowired
    private TransactionService service;

    @PostMapping("/transactions")
    ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody Transaction transaction){
        if(service.add(transaction))
            return new ResponseEntity<>(CREATED);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the issue is while converting milliseconds to Instant. Just for debugging purposes, can you convert data type of Transaction#timestamp to Long and then get Instant from Long?

Comment: Yes @YogeshBadke. The problem is with long to Instant conversion.  Basically Instant has 2 parts - epoch time and nanosec time. How do I make test pass? The input format cannot be changed

Comment: I changed the **Instant** type to long in the entire code. I was able to get over the BadRequest issue. However my test is still failing with 204 status. I am expecting 201. On further investigation turns out that the transaction instance created in the test and in the actual call  for add are different. Not sure why its different? Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is - Somehow when we use new java.time.Instant class in our code, long value of timestamp cannot directly map to Instant. Hence in the unit test using MvcMock, it always complained about BadRequest error. The issue got resolved by changing the Instant to long and then using Instant for date manipulation by converting long to Instant.
Also the issue of 204 error is natural. Both the instances will be different. Hence I changed my **when** statement like -

```
when(service.add(Mockito.any(Transaction.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

This turned the test green

Answer (score 0):

For me every time i get this error when i change for example the

```
when(service.add(transaction)).thenReturn(true);
```

to

```
when(service.add(Mockito.any(Transaction.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

it works but i am not sure why.